# Programmatically create a MIDI file from any LilyPond file

Tags: lilypond

I want to create a MIDI file from **any** LilyPond file, without having to manually add a `\midi { }` block.

Can this be done from the command line? Ideally I am looking for an option like `lilypond --midi`. The final goal is to create a shell script, `lilypond2midi`.

Answer (score 3):

The documentation makes it pretty clear that there is no such command-line option, so this isn't really a LilyPond question.

What you could do, however, is insert the `\midi` command into the LilyPond code dynamically within your shell script.

For example, your script could do something like this. (I haven't done any AWK in a while, but I think this works. [Perl](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perl) could also tackle this problem.)

```
awk '/^\\score/ {inScore=1}
     /^}/ {if (inScore == 1) print "\midi {}"
                             inScore=0
          }
     {print}' ${filename}.ly | lilypond -o $filename -
```

This assumes that the input file has a `\score` block and that the first closing brace, `}`, at the beginning of a line, after the `\score` block begins, is the closing of the `\score` block.

This doesn't alter the original LilyPond file, of course, but LilyPond will compile it as if it *did* have a `\midi` command.