# Create MIDI files from Lilypond snippet

Tags: midi, lilypond

This is not a duplicate question on [how to create a MIDI file from Lilypond](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34320723/programmatically-create-a-midi-file-from-any-lilypond-file). I have done that many times.

I have created some lilypond snippets, and I want to extract MIDI from them. Normally I would do that in the `\score` block like this:

```
\score {
  \music
  \layout { }
  \midi { }
}
```

But, my snippet does not contain a `\score` block; it is written like this:

```
\version "2.18.2"
\include "lilypond-book-preamble.ly"

\paper {
  indent = 2\mm
  line-width = 210\mm
}

\layout {
  indent = #0
  \context {
    \Score
    \remove "Bar_number_engraver"
  }
}

\relative c'
{
   \tempo 4 = 60
   \clef treble \key d \major g8^\markup { C } g8 b4   b8 b8 d4   cis8 cis8 e4  b8 b8 d4
}
```

This code creates a perfect PDF snippet. But I don't know where to put the `\midi { }` block to create a MIDI file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the easiest solution is to assign your music to a variable and create a `\score` block. Is there a reason why you are avoiding to use a `\score` block in your example? For instance, the code below generates both MIDI and pdf files:

```
\version "2.18.2"
\include "lilypond-book-preamble.ly"

\paper {
  indent = 2\mm
  line-width = 210\mm
}

\layout {
  indent = #0
  \context {
    \Score
    \remove "Bar_number_engraver"
  }
}

music = \relative c'
{
   \tempo 4 = 60
   \clef treble \key d \major g8^\markup { C } g8 b4   b8 b8 d4   cis8 cis8 e4  b8 b8 d4
}

\score{
  \music
  \layout{}
  \midi{}
}
```

Comment: Thanks Gilbert, I tried to avoid the `\score` block because I was always thinking that a `\score` block implicitely would create one or more "sheets" of music, whilst a snippet would create just a graphic with the dimensions that are required to fit the rendered elements. Now, as your example illustrates, I see this is not the case. I figured out that the line `\include "lilypond-book-preamble.ly"` is responsible for the "snippet" output; omitting this line will generate a full page PDF.

Comment: that's is all correct, great to hear this solved your problem!